# KnockoutJS: Wrapping the if binding in a custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am currently going over the documentation for creating custom bindings with Knockout, and I can grasp the concept, but I am having trouble applying it in practice.

Specifically, I want to provide a slideUp/slideDown jQuery animation to an if binding. However, I am having trouble just getting KO to "see" my custom binding. A point towards the right direction regarding extending if bindings would be much appreciated.

Additional notes:

I am using the KO external template engine from [here](https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine), like so:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'SummaryBox', if: expanded } --><!-- /ko -->
```

And I created a very basic custom binding to wrap around the default 'if':

```
ko.bindingHandlers['slidingIf'] = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers['if']['init'](element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers['if']['update'](element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context);
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings['slidingIf'] = true;
```

But when I replace the previous binding with this,

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'SummaryBox', slidingIf: expanded } --><!-- /ko -->
```

The template basically ignores the 'slidingIf' binding and just displays my template as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values passed to the `template` binding are options to that binding and not actually their own separate bindings.  So, the `template` binding itself does not know about your `slidingIf` binding.

You would either need to use your `slidingIf` binding on its own or write a wrapper to the `template` binding that does your animation.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and look for another approach that takes this into consideration once I get the time for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, but found that my "inner" bindings were failing, so I made this change:

`return ko.bindingHandlers['if']['update'].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));`